# Promise not resolving after connection completes

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I have a mongoose connect function in which I try to wait for reconnecting if the first attempt fails:

```
async connect() {
    const options = {...}
    try {
        console.log("starting")
        await this._connectWithRetry(options)
        console.log("finished")
    } catch (err) {
        winston.error(`Could not connect to Mongo with error: ${err}`)
    }
}

private async _connectWithRetry(options) {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            winston.info("Connecting to mongo...")
            await mongoose.connect(this.dbURI, options)
            winston.info("Connection successful.")
            resolve()
        } catch (err) {
            winston.info("Failed to connect to mongo. Retrying in 5 seconds...")
            setTimeout( async () => {
                await this._connectWithRetry(options)
            }, 5000)
        }
    })
}
```

It successfully waits until I'm connected. But once I connect, the second console line is not hit ("finished"). so I figure that my promise resolution is buggy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: `Promise.resolve()` is not the same as `resolve()`. Also, if the connection fails, the recursive call will create a new Promise and the original will disappear without settling, either, so that's no good.

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` returns a *new resolved promise*. However, if you call the `resolve()` argument, you are *resolving the promise it belongs to*.

Comment: If you go in the `catch` then you'd never resolve nor reject the first promise you create. If the second call succeeds, then you'd resolve a *different promise* while the first one would still be pending.

Comment: Try to remove async from inside Promise( async (resolve, reject) just Promise( (resolve, reject). That's my guess ;)

Comment: Does it print "connection successful"?

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

Your code "works" if the connection to the DB is established first time around.

If the retry mechanism is used, you will see the error you describe.

The `Promise` instantiated by the first call to `mongoDBConnect` is never resolved in the retry execution path.

This is because subsequent invocations of `mongoDBConnect` are made in a totally separate execution context on a future tick of the event loop, controlled by the `setTimeout` - and each invocation instantiates a new `Promise` totally disconnected from your `connect` function.

This refactoring should fix the issue:

```js
const delay = (interval) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval))

async connect() {
    const options = {...}
    try {
        console.log("starting")
        await this._connectWithRetry(options)
        console.log("finished")
    } catch (err) {
        winston.error(`Could not connect to Mongo with error: ${err}`)
    }
}

private async _connectWithRetry(options) {
    try {
        winston.info("Connecting to mongo...")
        await mongoose.connect(this.dbURI, options)
        winston.info("Connection successful.")
    } catch (err) {
        winston.info("Failed to connect to mongo. Retrying in 5 seconds...")
        await delay(5000)
        await this._connectWithRetry(options)
    }
}
```

Test harness:

```js
let retryCount = 0

const mongoose = {
    connect: ()=>retryCount++ === 2 ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject('fake error')
}

async function connect() {
    try {
        console.log("starting")
        await connectWithRetry()
        console.log("finished")
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`connect error`, err)
    }
}

async function connectWithRetry() {
    try {
        console.log("Connecting to mongo...")
        await mongoose.connect()
        console.log("Connection successful.")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Retrying in 1 second...", err)
        await delay(1000)
        await connectWithRetry()
    }
}

const delay = (interval) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval))

connect()
```

Comment: Inside `_connectWithRetry()`, `return this._connectWithRetry(options)` would (in general) make more sense than `await this._connectWithRetry(options)`. We can get away with `await` in this case as we're relying only on settlement of the returned Promise, not on its ability to deliver a result.